# Adding stylesheets to head dynamically with jQuery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking for to adding specific style-sheets to the `<head></head>` section of the current page. I can use jQuery, and the following jQuery snippet works. Problem is a php code calls those style-sheets and I need to integrate my php code into the jQuery, which I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
    $this->style()
            ->appendStylesheet($this->APP_STATIC_URL . '/templates/' . $this->APP_TEMPLATE . '/skins/' . $this->APP_SKIN . '/content_blog_view_{4}.css', 'screen')
            ->appendStylesheet($this->APP_STATIC_URL . '/templates/' . $this->APP_TEMPLATE . '/skins/' . $this->APP_SKIN . '/content_blog_view_{3}.css', 'screen')
            ->appendStylesheet($this->APP_STATIC_URL . '/templates/' . $this->APP_TEMPLATE . '/skins/' . $this->APP_SKIN . '/content_blog_view_{2}.css', 'screen')
            ->appendStylesheet($this->APP_STATIC_URL . '/templates/' . $this->APP_TEMPLATE . '/skins/' . $this->APP_SKIN . '/content_blog_view_{1}.css', 'screen');
    echo $this->style()->minify();
?>
```

It generates the following html code:

```
<link href="http://redspark/templates/default/skins/default/content_blog_view_{4}.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="http://redspark/templates/default/skins/default/content_blog_view_{3}.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="http://redspark/templates/default/skins/default/content_blog_view_{2}.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="http://redspark/templates/default/skins/default/content_blog_view_{1}.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

I need to add the above mentioned php code in the following jQuery code (or any other better solution you know).

```
<script>
var $head = $("head");
var $headlinklast = $head.find("link[rel='stylesheet']:last");
var linkElement = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/masterBlaster.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>";
if ($headlinklast.length){
   $headlinklast.after(linkElement);
}
else {
   $head.append(linkElement);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `echo` your PHP code in a Javascript variable and then use it.

Something like this:

```
var styles = "<?= echo $this->style()->minify(); ?>"
```